# "that" as a determiner or complementizer

Tags: that

- *On projects in the built environment, people consider safety and functionality nonnegotiable. But the aesthetics of a new project―how it is designed―is too often considered irrelevant ― The question of how its design affects human beings is rarely asked. People **think** **that** design makes something highfalutin, called architecture, and **that** architecture differs from building, just as surely as the Washington National Cathedral differs from the local community church.*

Q. I was curious about the grammatical role of the second **"that"**. Some teachers think it functions as a complementizer linked with the main verb **"think"**. Others think it functions as a determiner as in **"that cousin of ours"**.

Thank you for your feedback in advance

Comment: It seems pretty clearly just a repetition of the complementizer for the first complement clause. So they think architecture differs from building.

Comment: @John Lawler  Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: "People **think** [that design makes something highfalutin, called architecture, [and that architecture differs from building ...]".  The two bracketed expressions form a coordination of clauses serving as complement of "think". Both "thats" are subodinators.